# Angular PWA Regenerate Manifest

Tags: angular7, angular-pwa

According the the Angular docs here https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config I can run this command

```
ngsw-config dist src/ngsw-config.json /base/href
```

And the CLI should regenerate my service worker manifest.

However it doesn't work I just get the following error message

> zsh: command not found: ngsw-config

I have looked on npm, tried `npm run ngsw-config`, `ng ngsw-config` seems to me it doesn't exist. I am using angular 7.2

Maybe there is a new way to do this and the docs are out of date? If so what is the new way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work. You can edit the files and then you can use the command: ng build --prod
Now the ngsw-worker.js is in the dist folder